# Why using Array.prototype.push() on itself produces an infinitely nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I run this code:

```
const animals = ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep'];

animals.push(animals)
console.log(animals);
```

I get this error in my environment:

> Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Why does this produce an infinitely nested array?

Comment: You created an infinitely nested object. What did you expect as output?

Comment: `.push()` itself wont cause that issue. It is probably whatever is trying to log it. Your code works fine in the Chrome dev tools console.

Comment: I want konw why Array.push(self) will be an infinitely nested object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `animals.push(animals)` you must realise that what you push is also the array that receives the push, meaning that there is really *one* array that grows from length 3 to length 4. The fourth element is a reference to the array itself, which ... has a length of 4, ...etc. And so you get this result:

```
['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep',
    ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep',
        ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep',
            ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep',
                ...
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

It doesn't take infinite memory: it is *one* array that you could picture like this:

```
    animals (ref)
     │
     │  ┌───────────────────────────────┐
     v  v                               │ 
   ┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───│───────┐
   │ "pigs"   │ "goats"  │ "sheep"  │ (ref)     │
   └──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

If you just wanted to push `['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep']` without the recursion, then you need to create a new array with those values, so that it will not be affected by the `push`:

```
animals.push([...animals])
```

Now you will have this structure:

```
['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep', ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep']]
```

Which can be pictured like this:

```
    animals (ref)
     │
     │
     v
   ┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
   │ "pigs"   │ "goats"  │ "sheep"  │ (ref)     │
   └──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───│───────┘ 
     ┌──────────────────────────────────┘
     v
   ┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
   │ "pigs"   │ "goats"  │ "sheep"  │
   └──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Notice how the nested array is a *different* array -- having 3 entries instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an infinitely nested array, but trying to traverse it is an infinite recursion.

```
animals = [ 'dog', 'cat' ];
animals.push(animals);
animals.push('zebra');
```

When you say

```
console.log(animals);
```

What it does (pseudo-code here) is:

```
for(e = each element of the array)
    console.log(e);
```

element 0: dog
element 1: cat
element 2: an array - expand it!

to expand that (since it's the same array) it, in effect, starts over:

element 0: dog
element 1: cat
element 2: an array - expand it!

and so on forever.  It never gets to the 'zebra' entry at any level.

Boiling it down to its essence, it's what happens if a recursive function calls itself, unconditionally:

```
function recur()
{
 recur();
}
```